# How to open an existing named semaphore?

Tags: linux, ipc, semaphore

Obviously `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` are not required when opening an existing semaphore.

`O_CREAT` is required when creating a new semaphore.

`O_EXCL` is only meaningful when OR-ing with `O_CREAT`, specifying that if a semaphore with the given name already exists, then an error is returned.

[Linux manual page for sem_open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html) said that

> Definitions of the flags values can be obtained by including <fcntl.h>

but I did not find any flag in [fcntl.h](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/fcntl.h.0p.html) that told me how to open an existing semaphore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* const sem_name = "lock.sem";

    if (argc == 1) {
        sem_t* const sem = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

        if (sem == NULL) {
            perror("sem_open");
            return 1;
        }

        sem_wait(sem); // Will block
        sem_close(sem);

        sem_unlink(sem_name);
    } else {
        sem_t* const sem = sem_open(sem_name, 0);

        if (sem == NULL) {
            perror("sem_open");
            return 1;
        }

        sem_post(sem); // Will unblock the other process
        sem_close(sem);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the argument count to control the behavior of the program.

If I supply no parameters (i.e., when `argc == 1`), then the program will open the semaphore, creating it if it does not already exist; it initializes the value of the semaphore to `0`.  It then does a `sem_wait()` on the `sem` object.  Since the semaphore was initialized to `0`, this causes the process to block.

Now if I run a second instance of this same program, but this time with any non-zero number of arguments (i.e., when `argc != 1`), then the program will open the semaphore, but will not create it if it does not already exist.  Note here that I pass `0` for the `oflag` parameter (i.e., I'm not passing any flags).  The program then does a `sem_post()`, incrementing the semaphore from `0` to `1`.  This unblocks the first process.  Both processes will close their references to the semaphore, and terminate.

If I understand your question correctly, the second case is what you're looking for.

If I try to run the second case first (i.e., when there isn't a running instance of the first case), then I get:

```
$ ./a.out foo
sem_open: No such file or directory
```

That's comming from the call to `perror()` because a semaphore with the given name does not exist.

Comment: Manual page does not mention the situation where `oflag` is `0`. Can you tell me where to find it?

Comment: @AndyLin Flags are bit fields (i.e., each bit in some integral type represents one possible option). 0 is the absence of any flag.